# About tornado.gen.Task's usage - asynchronous request

Tags: asynchronous, tornado

below is my source:

```
class Get_Salt_Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        #yield tornado.gen.Task(tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 5)
        yield tornado.gen.Task(self.get_salt_from_db, 123)
        self.write("when i sleep 5s")

    def get_salt_from_db(self, params):
        print params
```

and I run it; the console reported that:
     *TypeError: get_salt_from_db() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'*
and I don't know why?

Comment: tornado.gen.Task(func, *args, **kwargs)
Adapts a callback-based asynchronous function for use in coroutines.

Takes a function (and optional additional arguments) and runs it with those arguments plus a callback keyword argument. The argument passed to the callback is returned as the result of the yield expression.

Changed in version 4.0: gen.Task is now a function that returns a Future, instead of a subclass of YieldPoint. It still behaves the same way when yielded.

Comment: I DO NOT understand it!!

Answer (score 2):

`gen.Task` is used to adapt a callback-based function to the coroutine style; it cannot be used to call synchronous functions. What you probably want is a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (standard in Python 3.2+, available with `pip install futures` on Python 2):

```
# global
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(NUM_THREADS)

@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    salt = yield executor.submit(self.get_salt_from_db)
```